# Tall background images are rotated but not wide ones

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have 4 images in a square that I move in a parallax scrolling fashion with the help of JavaScript for a cool effect on my website. The problem is that 2 of the images are tall (has more pixels vertically than horizontally) and these 2 images are causing me trouble because they get rotated 90 deg. The only solution I can see is if i rotate them in my JavaScript, however, this annoys me deeply and I'd like to find the root cause of this problem. It's very odd to me that the 2 wide images stay in their original orientation but the 2 tall ones are always rotated 90 deg anti-cw. Even if I rotated the original image file 90 deg cw, it always ends up in the same orientation in the browser, 90 deg anti-cw from it's correct orientation.

I have tried removing the EXIF, rotating the actual picture files to counteract this in all possible ways, image-orientation (this seems to only be working with FireFox, I use Chrome) and transform: rotate but this gets overwritten by JavaScript since I have a requestAnimationFrame running that constantly updates the images positions with transform: translate3d.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", scrollLoop, false);

function scrollLoop() {
  var image1 = document.querySelector("#image-1");
  var image2 = document.querySelector("#image-2");
  var image3 = document.querySelector("#image-3");
  var image4 = document.querySelector("#image-4");

  var yScrollPosition = window.scrollY;

  setTranslate(yScrollPosition * 0.1, 0, image1);
  setTranslate(0, yScrollPosition * 0.1, image2);
  setTranslate(0, yScrollPosition * -0.1, image3);
  setTranslate(yScrollPosition * -0.1, 0, image4);

  requestAnimationFrame(scrollLoop);
}

function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el) {
  el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, 0)";
}
```

```css
.parallax-container {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.parallax-window {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
}

#image-1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 130%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: url("image-1.jpg") no-repeat center center;
}

#image-2 {
  height: 130%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url("image-2.jpg") no-repeat center center;
}

#image-3 {
  height: 130%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: url("image-3.jpg") no-repeat center center;
}

#image-4 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 130%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url("image-4.jpg") no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax-container">
  <div class="parallax-window">
    <div id="image-1" class="image"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax-window">
    <div id="image-2" class="image"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax-window">
    <div id="image-3" class="image"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax-window">
    <div id="image-4" class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The only thing I can think of at this point is that it might have something to do with IntelliJ IDEA that I use. Because when I open the tall images in IntelliJ they are already rotated as they are in the browser.

Comment: Could you post external URL containing real images, because like that your code snippet is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem had nothing to do with my code as i suspected. The problem was the EXIF that i thought i got rid off but actually didn't. So to make sure i didn't have to deal with it i converted the image to png from jpg, because i learned that png does not support EXIF.

This solved my problem. So if anyone has had a similar problem where their tall images get flipped 90 deg for no apparent reason, try converting it to png.